# How to track no. of lines being parsed through ANTLR?

Tags: log4j, antlr4

I'm Parsing a file through ANTLR4. I'm in middle of writing grammar for all the possible keywords. So, I want to log the total no. of lines present in the input file and Total no. of lines parsed successfully so that I can able to log the overall percentage of the file being parsed and also I want to log remaining keywords for which I haven't prepared the grammar yet. My question is **Is it possible to do it?** If possible I want to know **how to do it programatically?**
I believe we have to do that logging in visitor/Listener in my case visitor but I can't able to come up with any logic.

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR4 tries to parse the whole file, recovering if an error occurs. So in most cases every line is parsed - even if errors occur during the parsing. The question is: What number do you want to display?

Probably you are interested in the line of the first error. You can do this by setting the ErrorHandler with `Parser.setErrorHandler` on your Parser class. The `ANTLRErrorStrategy` must be implemented, its method `reportError` is called with a `RecognitionException` containing the error location. **Get the line of this error and subtract one** to find the lines without error.

If you just want to skip lines with errors, the strategy is the same. Instead of displaying the first error, **count the different lines with errors** and subtract them from the number of all lines to get the number of parseable lines (this is a heuristic, sometimes an error is recovered lines later, than this heuristic fails).

Better do not try to do it with a visitor/listener. Error recovery sometimes could result in a pruned parse tree rather than one containing error nodes. And traversing the parse tree is not needed if you want to fail fast.

Comment: Oh it's not possible ah?

Comment: I refined my answer, yet I think it is possible, but it depends on your definition of *parsed line*.